# Initialize JavaScript object as global object for then use in Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, ros

I have a class which required to be init.

```
class ROS {
  static init() {
    // do ros initialization
    ROS.ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({
            url: 'ws://' + ROS.host + ':' + ROS.ws_port.toString()
        });
    // and so on
    }
  static topic_publisher(topic_name, msg){
    var topic = new ROSLIB.Topic({
            ros: ROS.ros,
            name: topic_name,
        });
        topic.publish(msg);
    }
}
```

If I want to publish a message to a topic (call the `topic_publisher`) I just need to do like this `ROS.topic_publisher("x_param', '0.1')`.

However, in those respected page, there should be a script which already called `ROS.init()` (at least one from all `scripts.js` which I imported).

I design the web in which consist of 4 `iframes` and 1 `parent`. Let say all of them need to use `ROS.topic_publisher("x_param', '0.1')`.

In the current design, I need to call `ROS.init()` across all page. It make the server to have 5 ROS clients.

I want to know, is there anyway for me to let the initialization once (in the parent maybe) and let the rest I frame only call `ROS.topic_publisher("x_param', '0.1')` without re-import or re-initialize the `ROS.init()`.

I also try to use `parent.object`. So it is become like this:

On parent page:

```
var obj = ROS.init();
ROS.topic_publisher("x_param', '0.1'); // success
```

on Iframe page:

```
var obj = parent.obj;
obj.ROS.topic_publisher("x_param', '0.1'); // error
```

Any information will be helpful... Thanks!

Comment: Are all of the iframes on the same origin as the parent?

Comment: shouldn't it be `parent.ROS.topic_publisher`? since `ROS.init` doesn't return anything `obj` will just be undefined and pointless ... you can just do `ROS.init()` in the parent

Comment: @Amadan yeah, all Iframe  are located on the same page. Same place (in the server).

Comment: @Bravo Tried but still not works, I also make sure the ```parent``` page finished first for then loaded the ```Iframe``` ( to make sure the web-socket connection).

Comment: `still not works` - you haven't described what happens that makes you say "it doesn't work" - do you get errors? you shouldn't need to call `parent.ROS.init` - so I hope you aren't

Comment: by the way ... `name: name` what is `name`? should that be `name: topic_name` ? and does `ROS.init()` return anything?

Comment: @Bravo Ah I see, my bad. Yap I tried your way. In the parent only call ```ROS.init()``` and on the ```iframe``` -> directly call ```parent.ROS.topic_publisher()```. The error is  ```undefined reference```. for ```name: name``` yeah, sorry it is typo.

Comment: @dummydeveloper - does `ROS.init` return something that is actually required? if not, I think I have a very simple solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues. The first one is, AFAIK, unlike `function`, `class` does not create a global binding, so `parent.ROS` will not find anything. The second, minor one is that you would need to load `ROSLIB` in each window. Thirdly, `init` here is not really necessary, unless there is more to it — a simple static declaration should do.

Something like this might work to alleviate all of them. (Note: the code is untested; I don't know what ROSLIB is)

```
window.ROS = class ROS {
  static ROSLIB = top.ROSLIB;
  static ros = top.ROS?.ros ?? new this.ROSLIB.Ros(...);

  static topic_publisher(topic_name, msg) {
    const topic = new this.ROSLIB.Topic(...);
    topic.publish(msg);
  }
}
```

Note that all this only works if the origin of `top` is the same as that of child windows. If not, you would have to use `postMessage` instead.

EDIT: Another idea is to not have `ROS` in each frame, but just the top one. (I believe this was the original concept that I misunderstood.) This is better, and only requires a tiny modification to the code:

```
// only in top window
window.ROS = class ROS {
  ...
};
ROS.init();
```

Then you can use `top.ROS.topic_publisher(...)` in any of the windows.

Comment: "and so on" suggests there's more to init :p Also, if ROS.xxx is called from the iframe, are you sure you'd need the ROSLIB in the iframes? seems like ROS.xxx would be executed in the parent window context

Comment: @Bravo `topic_publisher` executes in current context, and you can't instantiate `ROSLIB.Topic` without a `ROSLIB` reference.... but this gives me an idea :) As for `init`, the same structure will work with an `init` function — I just wanted to show an alternative.

Comment: I know, but the class ROS code exists only in the parent and is executing in parent is it not? where ROSLIB exists?

Comment: Ah. I misunderstood.

Comment: original code never does `obj = new ROS()` - so not sure why you added that :p

Comment: Big Thanks!, this approach run smoothly --> ```top.ROS.topic_publisher(...)```